# Understanding Skid Buffer Mechanism

Tags: fpga, verilog, buffer

I have some questions about http://fpgacpu.ca/fpga/Pipeline_Skid_Buffer.html

1) Why is skid buffer designed to be **2-entries FIFO** instead of just 1-entry FIFO ?

> However, pipelining handshaking is more complicated: simply adding a
>   pipeline register to the valid, ready, and data lines will work, but
>   now each transfer take two cycles to start, and two cycles to stop.

2) Quoted from the article , why **two cycles to start, and two cycles to stop** ?

Comment: 1. is perhaps answered by the section from  "Ideally, the input and output interfaces operate concurrently for maximum bandwidth: in the same clock cycle, a new data item is received on the input interface and put into a register, and that same register is simultaneously read out by the output interface.| down to| " ...
 We can imagine this extra buffer register as allowing the input interface to "skid" to a stop, rather than stopping immediately, which we'd previously found contradicts our pipelining requirements."

Comment: For 2, as I infer it: Simple pipelining (without skid buffer) of valid/data will delay the data going to receiver by 1 clock. Assuming the receiver gives out ready immideately, and pipelining ready will delay the handshake by 1 clock to the transmitter. Hence new valid/data can arrive only after 2 clocks (for successful handshake).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon why need the input interface to "skid" to a stop ? Do you have a simple timing waveform to explain the need to "skid" to a stop ?

Answer (score 5):

At least in one specific community (the one concerned with synchronous elastic systems), the capacity-2 buffer is called an elastic buffer (EB), and is NOT the simplest primitive.
As you noted, capacity-1 buffer is simpler, and indeed it's this capacity-1 buffer that is called "skid buffer" in the synchronous elastic community (see, e.g., [Automatic Pipelining of Elastic Systems](https://www.cs.upc.edu/%7Ejordicf/gavina/BIB/files/PhD_Galceran.pdf), Fig. 2.5 and Fig. 2.7).

The capacity-2 buffer then is just a sequence of a capacity-1 buffer and a usual register (plus control; there are obviously two ways to sequence those two).

So why is the OP article using a capacity-2 buffer? Because the article is about pipelining, so by definition, all data must be registered on every possible transaction. Capacity-1 buffer hits register 0 or 1 times, so it's not always registered. Capacity-2 buffer hits register 1 or 2 times, so is useful for pipelining.
To put it in a different way - one register is used for pipelining (to always shorten the length of combinational circuit) and the other register is used for "elasticity" (to not drop data on the floor when the downstream is stalled but upstream is still sending).

One important point is that when pipelining a path with a stalling protocol (ready/stall/stop, etc.), the stalling signal also has to be registered to avoid it limiting the clock rate. See [SELF: Specification and design of synchronous elastic circuits](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.99.9778&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for a short discussion of that (they propose using latches, but also acknowledge FFs may be needed in some cases, such as FPGAs).
From this observation follows the need for an *additional* data register to preserve a data item in case the upstream was sending when downstream stalled (this data item follows the one currently in the "main" register, and the design has to ensure this sequence is preserved).

Comment: **one register is used for pipelining (to always shorten the length of combinational circuit) and the other register is used for "elasticity" (to not drop data on the floor when the downstream is stalled but upstream is still sending).** <-- I am a bit confused on the need for second register. I suppose one register alone is also able to be used for "elasticity"

Comment: Elasticity is basically propagating downstream stall signal to the upstream. It ALSO has to be registered, otherwise your stall logic gets too long and will limit your clock rate, defeating the purpose of pipelining (well, you may get around that in special cases, but in general it has to be registered).

Comment: E.g., see http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.99.9778&rep=rep1&type=pdf for a very short motivation of the additional register.

Comment: TLDR: one register is ALWAYS full to make the output registered. Because the ready/stall signal is also registered, there is a latency of 1 cycle between downstream stalling and upstream stopping sending. Thus the buffer has to POTENTIALLY put one additional data item on a side (as the main register is ALWAYS full already), in the case when the upstream is sending and the downstream stalls.

Comment: **the buffer has to POTENTIALLY put one additional data item on a side (as the main register is ALWAYS full already), in the case when the upstream is sending and the downstream stalls.** <-- What about the VS ad VS' cells on figure 10 in page 4 of http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.99.9778&rep=rep1&type=pdf ?

Comment: **Elasticity is basically propagating downstream stall signal to the upstream** <-- but it seems like we need 2-registers buffers for **both directions** between upstream (sender) and downstream (receiver) ??

Comment: VS and VS' are two halves of one controller that use latches for the back pressure path). They control the (forward) data path, implemented using two latches with opposite phases. I am not aware of modern mainstream FPGA providing configurable latches.

Comment: In figure 10, Why the AND gates on top of VS and VS' cells depend on 'valid' signal from sender while the AND gate on top of the first version does not ?

Comment: Because the state machines in Fig. 8 are slightly different, so the controllers in Fig. 9 are slightly different (and so are their copies in Fig. 10). Note that the bottom of Fig. 10 is essentially Fig. 9 with the left and right flipped (and one of them also split).

Comment: I do not quite understand Figure 8.

What are  Vl*!Sr/E0    and  Vl*!Sr/Em,Es ?

Comment: The part before the slash is the condition for taking the transition, the part after the slash is the output. E.g., Vl*!Sr/E0 means: take this transition if the left is valid and the right is not stopped, and then enable the main FF. Vl*!Sr/Em,Es has the same condition, but the output is enabling both latches.

Comment: (1) however for Vl*!Sr/E0 , why enables ONLY the main FF ?           (2) What does it exactly mean by "/Sl,Vr,Sel" ?

Comment: Thank you for the references, this weekend has turned into an exercise in printing 20 years worth of cited papers on dataflow, elastic pipelines, latency-insensitive designs, all because of a couple of skid-buffer articles I found while trying to write some n->1 AXI Stream widgets... 

Comment: @experquisite Would you be able to share hyperlinks to your "20 years worth of cited papers on dataflow, elastic pipelines, latency-insensitive designs" as well as the couple of "skid-buffer articles" you found such that all of us here would benefit from them ?

Comment: Sure. It started with https://zipcpu.com/blog/2019/05/22/skidbuffer.html (and others of his), and http://fpgacpu.ca/fpga/Pipeline_Skid_Buffer.html and this thread https://twitter.com/elaforest/status/1123961226852229122

Comment: The most helpful papers for me were http://arcade.cs.columbia.edu/lid-memocode15.pdf and https://academiccommons.columbia.edu/doi/10.7916/d8-nwnq-r644/download but I read a bunch more. I wasn’t personally so interested in the ones that focused on automated transformations of RTL, just the ones that included Verilog and descriptions of alternate implementations, and basic descriptions of the problem and what drives the need for one buffer vs two as described above...

Comment: @experquisite WHY the last link : https://academiccommons.columbia.edu/doi/10.7916/d8-nwnq-r644/download does not use "skid buffer" or "elastic circuit" ??

Comment: @experquisite What are the purposes of the [signals "cstop" and "cdata"](http://arcade.cs.columbia.edu/lid-memocode15.pdf#page=2) ?

Comment: Those are the purely combinational signals of a pipeline stage wrapped in these elastic buffers, the “pearl” to the “shell” of some of the elastic papers.

Comment: To be perfectly clear, the parts of those papers that I appreciated were:

1. explaining that the outbound registers were to break combinational paths on the downstream data+valid lines
2. in order to register and break the combinational paths of the upstream ready/stop lines, you need an additional skid/auxiliary/overflow buffer to handle any data+valid (aka token) which is being crossed while the registered stop/!ready is waiting to be clocked
3. that the whole *point* of the skid buffer, therefore, is to register the *upstream* line

Comment: @experquisite But why need BOTH "input buffer" and "output buffer" ?

Comment: To register the output data + valid. I’m not sure if it’s strictly necessary if it’s going to a nearby buffered I put but I guess if the point is to neutralize wire delays then it makes sense?

Comment: @experquisite Why is the '1' pin of the second multiplexer inside the input buffer block fed a symbol of ⊥ ?

Comment: @experquisite How is "Hold" action different from "Buffer" action ?

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t really have time to explain every detail, it’s all in the papers.

Answer (score 1):

There are reasons for 2-entries FIFO.

See the following waveform

*o_axi_rready* is used to backpressure *o_axi_arvalid*

> // Note the cycle difference between o_axi_rvalid and o_axi_rready
>
> // thus the number of o_axi_rdata (d2 and d3) being dropped

[image]

[image]